# how to implement hover effect that fades in

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

when you hover over the left side (previous function) slides in and fades darker and vice versa for the right

here's what I got so far thanks to Deleteman

http://jsfiddle.net/pQzWp/

Comment: Are you talking about the larger image thumbnail that appears when hovering on small thumbnails in the right column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to do the following:

Inside the block element that holds the image, add two block elements like this:

```
 #element1 {
 position:absolute;
 left:0; 
 top:0
 width:30%;
 height:100%; 
}

 #element2 {
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top:0
  width:30%;
  height:100%;
 }
```

And the position of the image container, set it the position to be "relative".

Now, you can set events like this:

```
$("#element1").mouseover(function() {
    //show "prev" link
 });

$("#element2").mouseover(function() {
  //show "next" link
 });
```

Hope it helps!

**Edit**

Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/pQzWp/7/

Changed your framework to JQuery, since I don't know much about mootools, you can change the fadeIn and fadeOut effect for whatever you want.

Comment: thanks, that's interesting but ultimately I would like to have it function like the new description above.